# Array of items from a single column (multiple sheets) below a header

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to retrieve all items that fall below a header in a single column but by indexing multiple sheets. It needs to be dynamic and somehow manage to find the end point based off the next header in line.

I am not too familiar with Sheets and what arrays are available versus not. So I have tried HLOOKUP without any luck but believe it might be my best method?

```
=HLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,{1,2,Nth}until next header is identified)
```

I can't even provide a good example, I was attempting to tie together HLOOKUP, with LOOKUP (to find next header). I am thinking I need to just utilize more space and throw the header off to the left and use a standard VLOOKUP, but I was hoping to figure this out.

[image: Sheet 1] [image: Sheet2] [image: Sheet3]

Sheet 1 shows items that fall below TITLE 2, Sheet 2 is a range, Sheet 3 is a range.

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_beHuFc9eTxnIHpez2EAc-L76y32PWmh_8XEUZJbPdE/edit?usp=sharing)

P.S. **All** items and headers will be unique.

Comment: it's not an answer, but putting data in a sheet with this format is an antipattern. It would be a good idea to change the format of your sheet altogether. I.e 2 columns where 1 is the item and 2 is the title. Then you have pairs like item1 title1, item2 title1 etc. Thats makes working with the sheet also much easier, as you just notice yourself, in this format it can be tricky and cumbersome. Thats just because the data is stored in a way that isnt the intended way of a spread sheet. In a sql database for example, you couldnt even store the data like this in a single table.

Comment: can you first write some arrayformulas on sheet2 and sheet3?  if you can spare a column on each of those tabs, it will make things easier for you.

Comment: @theFool I agree with your observation. I wasn't sure if there is a working way to implement this easily without altering the sheet but that is probably my best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can feed your dropdown from a range:

[image]

and then you can do:

```
=QUERY(FILTER({A1:A6; A7:A10; A11:A15}, 
 ISERROR(MATCH({A1:A6; A7:A10; A11:A15}, Sheet1!C:C)));
 "where Col1 is not null"; )
```

[image]

---

## update:

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IksiKWkqIlOJdZTa0iCIeCVpiYrWuph5HGZP27mdL6g/edit#gid=0)

Comment: I don't think I understand how to use the formula you provided to retrieve just the items that fall below a header? Such as return items 1-5 only, when Title 1 is searched.

Comment: @KevinP. see this example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IksiKWkqIlOJdZTa0iCIeCVpiYrWuph5HGZP27mdL6g/edit#gid=0